# Discord: How to enable slash commands in message reply?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've created slash commands, and they do work. I now wish to enable these slash commands in Discord message replies.
Currently, when I reply to a message and check the `/` context menu, I can only see "Built-in" commands. Is it possible to add my custom commands in case of a message reply?

Answer (score 2):

The feature is not implemented yet. Follow feature request here: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/1500001128682-Ability-to-add-custom-slash-commands-on-reply

Comment: Note that this seems to work in the Android app so it is implemented and likely a bug. Aside from this, discord doesn't seem to care that much about feature requests on their feedback forum.

Comment: Looks like they never followed with this, I am attempting to do something similar and it is still not supported.